# Skyrim exploding bolts

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How long does it take for them to re-supply. I've come back periodically and they been here I'm just trying to figure out so I can always come back and shorter time to stock up

Answer (score 3):

Merchants restock their items after you have been gone for 48 hours. If you return to their cell before 48 hours have passed, the timer will reset.